# SugarCRM REST API and jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, authentication, sugarcrm

I am trying to login to SugarCRM using jQuery and Sugar REST API and i want to create a html 5 app please tell me how to authenticate to sugarCRM in my html file.